# Bootstrap modal dialog dismiss not working but submit button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem which I seam to find no answer to. I have modal which contains a form for submitting data to the server. The submitting part is working just fine. All data gets send and the server takes the correct steps. However, the buttons to close/dismiss the modal do not work. The form gets pulled by ajax request from the server and is embedded in the current page

```
<!-- Dialog for user input of forms-->
<div id="form-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

</div>
```

Ajax pulled form

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <!-- Content of dialog -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Datensatz erstellen</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times

            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form action="{% url 'knowledgeedit' %}" method="POST" id="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div id="{{ field.auto_id }}_container">
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                    <div>
                        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="{{ requestedForm }}">Speichern</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    padding-top: 54px;
    color: #868e96;
}
.btn-primary{
  background-color: #bd5d38 !important;
  border-color: #868e96 !important;
}

/* Sections */



@media (min-width:992px) {
    body {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 17rem;
}
}h1, h2,h3,h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a25137;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    line-height: 5.5rem;
    color: #e78e3f
}
h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}
.subheading {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', serif;
    font-size: 1.35rem;
    color: #0a0e14;
}
.list-social-icons a {
    color: #495057;
}
.list-social-icons a:hover {
    color: #bd5d38;
}
.list-social-icons a .fa-lg {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}
.list-icons {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.list-icons .list-inline-item i:hover {
    color: #bd5d38;
}
#sideNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
    #sideNav {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 100vh;
}
#sideNav .navbar-brand {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto auto 0;
    padding: .5rem;
}
#sideNav .navbar-brand .img-profile {
    max-width: 10rem;
    max-height: 10rem;
    border: .5rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
#sideNav .navbar-collapse {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-grow: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
#sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%}
#sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
}
#sideNav .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    display: block;
}
}section.resume-section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    padding-top: 5rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 5rem!important;
}
section.resume-section .resume-item .resume-date {
    min-width: none;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    section.resume-section {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
section.resume-section .resume-item .resume-date {
    min-width: 18rem;
}
}@media (min-width:992px) {
    section.resume-section {
    padding-top: 3rem!important;
    padding-bottom: 3rem!important;
}
}.bg-primary {
    background-color: #bd5d38!important;
}
.text-primary {
    color: #bd5d38!important;
}
a {
    color: #bd5d38;
}
a:active, a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #824027;
}
```

Comment: The `submit` button is not working because it's outside the `form`. Move it inside the `form`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901759/1925257

Comment: As I commented in the last answer which was somehow deleted, I did that as well and it is still not working. Also, not the send is my problem since all data gets send and is received by the server as planned. My problem is the modal which can not be closed bei neither one of the two buttons or clicking on the original page

Comment: `<div class="modal-dialog"> ... </div>` should be inside `<div class="modal fade"> ... </div>`. From, your question, it looks like it's outside of it.

Comment: It is embedded, the actual dialog and the containing form are rendered by a seperate template and loaded via ajax so in the end it is withing <div class="modal-dialog"> ... </div>

Comment: I´m quite not sure what the exact cause was but I ended up fixing the problem my replacing my boostrap files with new ones. Thanks for the help